# Dropdown based data query website - how to extract the underlying data?

Tags: web, web-scraping, dropdown

The url of the website I am interested is http://www.cambridgeinternational.org/i-want-to/find-a-cambridge-school/ and as you can see, I must select the country and the city in order to see the data.

[image: screenshot from the website]

Anyone experienced this please tell me how I can go about extracting all rows from this particular table?

Answer (score 1):

You can use php script

```
if(isset(#id of country) and isset(#id of city )){
<script>  document.getElementById("").innnHTML = #data you want to show </script>

}
```

i think i am write.

Comment: Im a bit of beginner with web - where would u run this ?